# max wide isn't not working

Tags: html, css, width, max

```
<style> #gallery_t_ta {position: fixed; top: 15%; left: -10px; width: 300px; border-radius: 10px; background-color: #ffffff; padding: 10px; width: calc(100% - 310px); max-width: calc(100% - 310px); height: 100px; max-height: 100px; overflow-x: auto;} #gallery_t_ta td{width: 150px; max-width: 150px !important; overflow-y: hidden;}</style>
<table id="gallery_t_ta">
<tr>
    <td>
        <span id="t1n">Twister 10ct (2pk)</span><br>
        <img src="./product/twister.png" height="50" width="50"><br>
        <span id="t1p">9.00</span><br>
        <button onclick="add1()">Add To Cart</button> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <span id="t1n">Twister 10ct (2pk)</span><br>
        <img src="./product/twister.png" height="50" width="50"><br>
        <span id="t1p">9.00</span><br>
        <button onclick="add1()">Add To Cart</button> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <span id="t1n">Twister 10ct (2pk)</span><br>
        <img src="./product/twister.png" height="50" width="50"><br>
        <span id="t1p">9.00</span><br>
        <button onclick="add1()">Add To Cart</button> 
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

ok so i have this.  width isn't working on the td it keeps shrinking when i ad more td's.  also x scroll isn't working.

Is this not possible?

I want to be able to scroll left and right for all the items.
I have done with with y scroll before, maybe it isn't possible with x.

Answer (score 0):

Set a `min-width:150px;` on the `<td>`

```
#gallery_t_ta td{
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set **min-width: 150px;**

Also I think you need x-scroll
I hope some code below helping your issue.

```html
<style>
    #gallery_t_ta td{
        min-width: 150px;
    }
</style>
<div style="max-width: 150px; overflow-x: auto;">
    <table id="gallery_t_ta">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id="t1n">Twister 10ct (2pk)</span><br>
                <span id="t1p">9.00</span><br>
                <button onclick="">Add To Cart</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="t2n">Twister 10ct (2pk)</span><br>
                <span id="t2p">9.00</span><br>
                <button onclick="">Add To Cart</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="t3n">Twister 10ct (2pk)</span><br>
                <span id="t3p">9.00</span><br>
                <button onclick="">Add To Cart</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your `<td>` element a `width` or a `min-width`.

```
#gallery_t_ta td{
    width: 150px;
}
```

Also, instead of using CSS inline in your tags or in the `<head>` of your HTML file, it's best practice to put all of your CSS into a separate file and link it with:

```
<link href=yourfile.css rel=stylesheet type=text/css>
```

This keeps your code cleaner, and will save you a lot of trouble in the future when you are using your CSS to apply styles to multiple HTML pages.  That way you won't have redundant code that you have to update in multiple places to make a single change.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style> #gallery {position: fixed; top: 15%; left: -10px; background-color: #ffffff; width: calc(100% - 310px); max-width: calc(100% - 310px); height: 150px; max-height: 150px; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden; border-radius: 10px;} #gallery td{min-width: 150px; min-height: 150px; max-width: 150px; max-height: 150px;}</style>

<div id="gallery">
<table><tr><td>
        <span id="t1n">Twister 10ct (2pk)</span><br>
        <img src="./product/twister.png" height="50" width="50"><br>
        <span id="t1p">9.00</span><br>
        <button onclick="add1()">Add To Cart</button> 
    </td>

    <td>
        <span id="t1n">Twister 10ct (2pk)</span><br>
        <img src="./product/twister.png" height="50" width="50"><br>
        <span id="t1p">9.00</span><br>
        <button onclick="add1()">Add To Cart</button> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <span id="t1n">Twister 10ct (2pk)</span><br>
        <img src="./product/twister.png" height="50" width="50"><br>
        <span id="t1p">9.00</span><br>
        <button onclick="add1()">Add To Cart</button> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <span id="t1n">Twister 10ct (2pk)</span><br>
        <img src="./product/twister.png" height="50" width="50"><br>
        <span id="t1p">9.00</span><br>
        <button onclick="add1()">Add To Cart</button>
    </td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Fixed it.  This works if anyone else has this problem.  Down side it changes the bottom of the div (rounded edges) to a square one.